# Saving a full dataframe to disk as IPython shows it

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

Is there any way to save a DataFrame to disk as a string, using the format and alignment that IPython uses to display it?

Note that I would like to save the full dataframe, and not just  a summary (i.e. head & tail) of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPython is showing the `repr` of the dataframe:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(repr(df))
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if that would save the full dataframe or just the summary?

Comment: That depends on the value of `pd.options.display.max_rows`. The default is 60. If you set `pd.options.display.max_rows = float('inf')` then all rows will be shown.

Comment: Hmm, I get: `Value must be int`

Comment: Hm. My mistake. use `pd.options.display.max_rows = None`.